# Poem Identification from a stanza(?) containing “the midnight train” repeatedly

Tags: poetry, identification-request

> And in the midnight train
>   A cold wind blows through the rain
>   A child laughs an adults cry
>   Leads to pain and sacrifice
>   Toward the tracks of the unknown
>   The icy river icy cold flows
>   Trapped by dispair and running on empty
>   The urge to main, to kill, is tempting
>   Onward and onward til the moon rises high
>   Onward and onward he swiftly rides
>   Then the pain is no more
>   And comes face to face with scorn
>   Here we, the fallen five hundred, bled
>   and they are the ones who fled
>   throughout the midnight train
>   those who tremble in fear are our bane

That’s all that I apparently copied at the time, no title or author. I’ve tried Google, but no matches.